# How to run a terminal with clean environment from Python

Tags: python, linux, bash

I need to run a terminal from my Python script and execute a command in clean environment, as if I just opened terminal emulator and typed the command there. But I have some exported variables in my script that should not be available in this terminal. There can be an arbitrary number of variables (some of them may be even set outside the script using bash 'export' command), so I can't delete them manually before running the terminal.

I tried the common solution which is claimed to reset the default environment, but it did not work. The code looks like this:

```
import subprocess
import os

os.environ['X'] = 'Y'

cmd = 'gnome-terminal -x env -i bash -c "echo $X; bash --noprofile --norc"'
subprocess.Popen([cmd], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

The output still prints "Y". When I try to do the same thing using only terminal, the result is the same:

```
$ export X=Y
$ gnome-terminal -x env -i bash -c "echo $X; bash --noprofile --norc"
```

The new terminal is opened and "Y" is printed.

Is there any solution that could solve the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `env` argument when calling `subprocess.Popen`:

```
subprocess.Popen([cmd], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, env={})
```

This will run it in as clean environment as possible, however a lot of maybe needed environment variables will be missing. You may want to cache `os.environ` when you start your script and then populate the `env` argument with that cache to get the same environment variables you had when you started your script.

Update (for clarity sake): Keep in mind that the current environment is always copied to any sub-process (and sub-processes cannot access/change the environment of their parents) so the above essentially takes the current environment and blanks it out (giving the sub-process copy of an empty environment) and if the sub-process cannot establish new environment it will never know the variables from your script's environment. One way to partially mitigate that is to actually let bash (or whatever shell you're calling from your sub-process) to load profile and other user scripts but it still won't get the global environment.

Comment: I tried this solution, but for some reason if I add `env={}` the terminal does not open at all, probably because some important variables are erased it this case.

Comment: If you can't identify the environment variables needed to run your command successfully, as soon as you run your script store your environment variables in some cache (e.g. `env_cache = os.environ.copy()`) and then use this cache later on as `env` argument to `Popen`. If you want to erase env. changes in shell even before executing your script, you cannot as you don't have a track of them.

Comment: That being said, try changing your command to execute `env -i` *after* `bash -c` (so within the command itself) - I have a feeling that `bash -c` is picking up your environment variables from profile and other files and that `$X` is actually defined in one of those.

Comment: Yes, I tried `gnome-terminal -x bash -c env -i "echo $X; bash --noprofile --norc"` but it this case the terminal shows up and disappears immediately, and nothing happens. I tried to `touch` the file instead of `echo` and it does not work

Comment: No, I meant have your command set to: `gnome-terminal -x "env -i bash --noprofile --norc"` or something like that (I don't see why you need gnome-terminal in the first place, I'd run your command as: `env -i bash --noprofile --norc`)

Comment: Strange , when I try `env={}` from a Python 3.8.10, it seems to work - but if I try it from a Python 3.10.12 I get `OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect` (but they also run in different environments)